# PyGame paddle board not moving

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

The key events are being registered fine on the console. Also, my paddle is showing up which suggests that my paddle class called from another file works. However, I would like my paddle to move smoothly when the left arrow key or the right arrow key is pressed down so the user does not have to repeatedly click. However, with my current code, the paddle does not move at all. I've tried changing around the position of the if/else statement that changes position to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

The main game:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from Config import Config 
from Paddle import Paddle

pygame.init()

#--Display settings
pygame.display.set_caption(Config['game']['caption'])
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((Config['game']['display_width'], 
Config['game']['display_height']))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
paddle= Paddle(game_display)

x_change = 0
pressed_left = False
pressed_right = False

def event_handler():
for event in pygame.event.get():
    print (event)
    if (event.type == QUIT) or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == 
K_ESCAPE):
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    #To move the paddle to the left and right
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            pressed_left = True  
        elif event.key== K_RIGHT:
            pressed_right = True

    #If the key is up
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            pressed_left = False
            x_change = 0
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            pressed_right = False 
            x_change = 0

#--This changes the position
if pressed_left:
    x_change = -5
if pressed_right:
    x_change = 5

while True:
    event_handler()
    game_display.fill(Config['colors']['white'])
    paddle.draw()
    paddle.movement(x_change)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(Config['game']['fps'])
```

And from my paddle.py that contains the Paddle class:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from Config import Config

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, game_display):
        self.x = (Config['game']['display_width'] * 0.45)
        self.y = (Config['game']['display_height'] * 0.92)
        self.game_display=game_display


    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.game_display, Config['colors']['red'], 
[self.x, self.y, 40, 25])

    def movement(self, x_change):
        self.x += x_change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler example. Try running this program.

```
pressed_left = False
def event_handler():
    pressed_left = True

event_handler()

print(pressed_left)
```

While you expected the program to print `True`, it prints `False`. This happens due to the way variable scoping works in python. When you try to modify a variable in a function that isn't defined in that function itself, python defines a new variable instead of looking for a global one.
So, the `pressed_left = True` line in `event_handler()` just creates a new `pressed_left` variable that exists solely in the `event_handler` function without modifying the global one.

To solve this, you need to declare the variable as global in the function. Try running this program.

```
pressed_left = False
def event_handler():
    global pressed_left
    pressed_left = True

event_handler()

print(pressed_left)
```

Comment: I added this because this solution makes sense. However, pressed_left and pressed_right are still being registered as False and the key presses, while registered, don't change the value of the varibles to from False to True. Thank you for this much though!

Comment: I changed the top of the event_handler function to include the global declarations.Sorry, I'm trying to get the formatting right:

Comment: @HasanatJahan Can you share the Config file as well so I can try running the program

Comment: Sure!
`Config = {
 'game' : {
  'caption' : 'Breakout',
  'display_width' : 800,
  'display_height' : 600,
  'fps': 80
 },

 'colors' : {
  'black' : (0, 0, 0),
  'white' : (255, 255, 255),
  'red' : (255, 0, 0)
 }

}`

Comment: And the top of my event handler now looks like this:
`def event_handler():

 global pressed_left

 global pressed_right

 global x_change

 #--Gets every event on the screen

 for event in pygame.event.get():`...

Comment: @HasanatJahan Why is the x_change update not part of event handler function. It's not run in the loop either.

Comment: I just changed it the x_change update inside the event handler function and it worked. The paddle is moving. Thank you kind wizard.

Answer (score 0):

change your keys to something like this

```
key = pygame.key.pressed()

if key[pygame.K_left]:
    pygame movement
```

Comment: Why is this a better alternative? Why would this solve the problem of pressed_left and pressed_right as being registered as false?

Comment: because the player will constantly move until the ey as stopped being pressed